# Search api autocomplete with commerce kickstart

Tags: views, search, commerce

i am using search api with commerce kickstart i have created a view and used it as an exposed form on the homepage, I have used the search api autocomplete module but its not working because the server is not supported. So I have made a custom module to do the autocomplete feature for my search filter block. This is the code

```
<?php

function ajaxforms_menu() {  
$items['ajaxforms/autocomplete'] = array(
'page callback' => 'ajaxforms_products',
'access arguments' => array('access ajax autocomplete'),
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
);
return $items;
}


function ajaxforms_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form-display_products-page') {
$form['#submit'][] = 'ajaxforms_submit_funtion';
}
}
function ajaxforms_submit_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
$search_str = $form_state['values']['views-exposed-form-display-products-page'];
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
drupal_goto('path_to_your_search_view', array('query' => array('search_api_view_fulltext' => $search_str)));
}

function ajaxforms_products($string) {
$matches = array();

// DB table which holds products
$query = db_select('commerce_product', 'p');

// Select rows that match the string
$return = $query
->fields('p', array('title'))
->condition('p.title', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
->range(0, 10)
->execute();

// add matches to $matches
foreach ($return as $row) {
$matches[$row->title] = check_plain($row->title);
}

drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```

But its not working I dont know where I am wrong on this. Anyone have any idea on how to solve this ? I want the autocomplete in the block of the exposed filter search which I am using as a block

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question or did I missed anything because its been sometime that I have posted it and its not been answered yet. Please let me know if I missed something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using this example [jQuery Autocomplete](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step)

If anyone else get stuck in this just ask me and I'll try to help out

Comment: +1, Hi H_alt can you please help me with this, do you have custom module package ? if not how can I integrate with the custom module, I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Yes i do have a custom module but it was not intended for this I just added the js files myself and provided the id of the search textfield in the js(jquery) file and it worked. I never used the actual drupal way to achieve that bcoz I was new(well still am) and couldnt get around it. Still trying to get it done though the drupal way.

Comment: Thanks fro your reply I done it with this module https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_autocomplete

Comment: In my case this module is not working it does not support the server or the service that the site is built on...Good if it worked for you.